# Linq join to form a new json

Tags: c#, linq

[image]

i want to achieve the following

- Form a json like below image with the result of the linq in c# web api 2

[image]

Note : I will use this json to form a tree view using angularjs

Json explained :

Dashboard is the main module name and Master is the sub module name and under this sub module i should have the screens (User Creation and GH User Creation) with the module id.This will be a repeat process for all modules and sub modules that i add.

End result :

> Dashboard (Module Name)
>   - Master (Sub Module Name)
>     -- User Creation
>     -- GH User Creation
>
> Booking (Module Name) 
>   -Confirm Booking (Sub Module Name)
>    --Booking Tool

If more info needed i can provide it & Thanks in advance :)

My incomplete c# code :    Here is my code which i think is worst if all :D

```
public Rolesandrights Get()
    {
        var result = new Rolesandrights();

            var headermodule= (from t1 in db.mapheadermodules
                               join t2 in db.HeaderModules
                              on t1.moduleid equals t2.ModuleId into t3

                               select new Rolesandrights()
                               {

                                   moduleid=t1.moduleid,
                                   modulename=t3.FirstOrDefault().Module_Name,
                                   submodulename=t1.submodulename

                               }).ToArray();

        var groupbyscreenname = (from t1 in db.mapheadermodules
                            join t2 in db.HeaderModules
                           on t1.moduleid equals t2.ModuleId into t3

                            select new assignrights()
                            {

                                screenname = t1.screenname

                            }).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in headermodule)
        {
            result.moduleid = item.moduleid;
            result.modulename = item.modulename;
            result.submodulename = item.submodulename;

            foreach (var data in groupbyscreenname)
            {


            }



        }

        return result;
    }
```

Class which i created :

```
 public class Rolesandrights
{
    public string rolename { get; set; }

    public int createdby { get; set; }

    public DateTime createddate { get; set; }

    public string status { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public int moduleid { get; set; }

    public string modulename { get; set; }

    public string submodulename { get; set; }

    public string statename { get; set; }

    public string screenname { get; set; }

    public assignrights[] assignrights { get; set; }
}


public class assignrights
{
    public string screenname { get; set; }

}
```

My angular controller :

```
$http({
    url: $rootScope.ServiceBaseUri + 'Rolesrights/listscreenmaster',
    method: "GET"
}).then(function (response) {
    debugger;
    $scope.screenlist = response.data.assignrights;
    $scope.list = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.screenlist, function (item) {

        $scope.jsonrepeat = {

            name: item.modulename,
            children: [{
                name: item.submodulename,
                children:[{
                name:item.screenname

                }]

            }]

        }

        $scope.list.push($scope.jsonrepeat);

    })

}, function (error) {

});
```

Comment: What have you done? Show your unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: Updated with code.Thanks !

Comment: At first, your example JSON is misformatted. Have you interested of children names only? In that case, maybe an array of names preferable that array of objects with only property `name`?

Comment: Yes Sub module will be the children of Module and screen names will be children of the sub modules.Yeah i missed a square bracket in example json.

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/sliiice/pen/GurpF)                                                This is what i am trying to do.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan any idea on this on how to do it correct ??